# How to check the version of Magento from URL?

Tags: magento-community, version

I want to know the programmable logic of getting the magento version by just entering URL of the magento store.Something similar is seen here.

http://magentoversion.com/

Comment: What's the point of that service? Just log in into the backend and you'll see it there too.

Comment: This is for fingerprinting a Magento site that you don't have backend access to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally after long research I found Following code useful to determine Version of Magento.

```
    <?php
function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
} 
$file = $url.'/skin/frontend/default/default/css/styles.css';
$data = get_data($file);
$data   = explode("\n", $data);
for ($line = 0; $line < count($data); $line++)
 {
    if(strpos($data[$line],"2010" )){$mver= 1.5;}
    elseif(strpos($data[$line],"2011")){$mver= 1.6;}
    elseif(strpos($data[$line],"2012")){$mver= 1.7;}
    elseif(strpos($data[$line],"2013")){$mver= 1.8;}
    elseif(strpos($data[$line],"2014")){$mver= 1.9;}
}

?>
```

I hope it would help you all

Answer (score 2):

<del>https://github.com/steverobbins/magento-guest-audit/blob/master/src/MGA/Check/Version.php</del>*(broken)*
https://github.com/steverobbins/magescan/blob/master/src/MageScan/Check/Version.php

MGA fetches js/varien/product.js, and then pulls license information and the copyright year from the header to guess at the version. Note that it can't differentiate 1.4 from 1.5 this way - if you cared enough you could keep a list of hashes of each JS file and track changes in more detail.

Comment: Can you explain me this code in deep please I am not getting it.